# View Background problems

Tags: android

This happened a couple of days ago. Still cannot find the way to fix it.

Here is a simple test project.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03903482111052488979

Pretty simple layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/input_hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Enter"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle important parts:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

**Ple-lollipop devices (genymotion and real devices)**

The background (pressed, sometimes normal) looks like something wrong with 9-patch file. Some of affected views - item in navigation view, menu item, edittext
edittext - https://gyazo.com/71f13003a46ff596514e475a72f924b7
pressed menu item - https://gyazo.com/7a5d9db29e17524e353f10a18562786e

**Lollipop until 5.1**

Crashes on startup (stop crashing on appcompat 23.1.1 and lower)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ww.aeli.wtf.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020015                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2428)
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(NinePatchDrawable.java:445)
```

**Lollipop 5.1 and marshmallow**

Everything works fine

**What have i tried**

Problem also was reproduced on other developer machine.

Downgrading appcompat till the version 23.0.0. Lollipop do not crashes on 23.1.1 and lower, but background problem persists.

Disabling vector support (the main 23.2.0 feature, that theoretically could affect).

Similar recent problems - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467 (the discussion went on the strange way), https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1081, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210547

older one:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i find the way to "fix" all the issues as always just after posting a question.

Downgrading the gradle version from 2.2.0-alpha1 to 2.1.+ will solve all the problems.

And again note to myself - never use "+" in library versions.

Comment: Confirmed using Gradle 2.1.2 fixed the problem. The issue for me might have had to do with swapping between Android Studio beta and stable